# How to copy only single column from table to another(Same database) in sql without using Inner join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables in World,

```
city2(ID,Name,Countrycode,district,population)
city(ID,Name,Countrycode,district,population)
```

I only want to copy(i.e update) NAME from `city` to `city2`. How can I do that?

Is it possible how to select copy multiple columns from `city` to `city2`?

Comment: why do you want to avoid using a `join`?

Comment: because right now i haven't started dealing with inner joins concept so what to know whether the above operation is possible or not .

Answer (score 2):

To do just a "copy" you would do this:

```
INSERT INTO CITY2(name)
  SELECT NAME FROM CITY1
```

For multiple columns just add to the select list and the list of columns after CITY2

```
INSERT INTO CITY2(name,Countrycode)
  SELECT NAME, Countrycode FROM CITY1
```

To UPDATE do this

```
UPDATE CITY2 c2
JOIN CITY c ON c.ID = c2.ID
  SET c2.NAME = c.NAME
```

UPDATE mutiple columns just add to the set

```
UPDATE CITY2 c2
JOIN CITY c ON c.ID = c2.ID
  SET c2.NAME = c.NAME, c2.Countrycode = c.Countrycode
```

Comment: thanks for answering 
first i created both the tables
then inserted few columns from city to city2 successfully

insert into city2(ID,Names) select ID,Name from city;

but when i am performing the next insert with CountryCodes

insert into city2 (CountryCode) select CountryCode from city;

in mysql it says
4079 row(s) affected Records: 4079  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

and when i check i see only null in all the rows of CountryCode.

Comment: @arun3x3 - yes after you insert some records you have to update those records... like I show in the 2nd two queries.  However, I wonder why you didn't just insert the country code on the initial insert.

Comment: i want copy one column after other whenever i want and need to. i want to know whether their is such choice or not .
Thanks for your reply i think i have to go with join concepts to achieve this operation.

Comment: @arun3x3 then use the update statement in my answer.  What is your problem here?